# DataGridView navigate cell on KeyUp with wrapped text

Tags: winforms, datagridview

[image]

I would expect to navigate to the other cell only when reaching the very top.
What actually happens is that it navigates on hitting the 'up' key at the fourth line (which would the first line, if not for the text wrap).

Do you know if it is 'by design' or can be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling of the keyboard input is a responsability shared by the editing controls (classes implementing `IDataGridViewEditingControl`) inside the `DataGridView` and the `DataGridView` itself.

If you look at the source code inside [DataGridView](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,2cc4e2a42be6fd3c), you will see that the decision of where to handle a key press is demanded to the editing controls. Basically, the DataGridView asks to the `IDataGridViewEditingControl` (in your case, a `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl`) "Do you want to handle it?" by calling the 
[EditingControlWantsInputKey](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl.cs,132) method.

This method contains a bug, or better an over-semplifications. The intent of the code seems to be "if I am already on the first line, a KeyUp means that the user wants to move to the cell above me". Unfortunately, "first line" is, in the code, anything before the first `\r\n`, disregarding word wrap. Which is what you are observing.

Fortunately `EditingControlWantsInputKey` is public virtual, so you can derive from `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl` and adjust the behaviour corresponding to your needs.

For example:

```
public class MyDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl : DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl {
   public override bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys keyData, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey) {
        switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Up:
               return false; // never pass KeyUp to the DataGrid
        ...
        // call base.EditingControlWantsInputKey when
        // you want to retain the standard behaviour
```

This is oversimplified (it just disables the "move to the cell above" behaviour; you might want to act differently, maybe measuring the text lenght fitting in the "real" first line inside the cell by using [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx). This is up to you and what you want to obtain.

Then, it is relatively easy to [replace the standard controls for DataGridView cells with your own](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.110).aspx).